# error handler in a testcase verification helper

Tags: python, pytest

Having a verification helper function (which would be called by various testcases with different boolean values passed for `raise_on_error`):

```
def verify_multiply(a: int, b: int, c: int, raise_on_error=True):
    if a * b == c:
        return True
    else:
        error_msg = f"{a} * {b} != {c}"
        if raise_on_error:
            raise ValueError(error_msg)
        else:
            log.error(error_msg)
            return False
```

I wanted to replace the error handler with a wrapper like:

```
def error_handler(error_msg, raise_on_error=True):
    if raise_on_error:
        raise ValueError(error_msg)
    else:
        log.error(error_msg)
        return False
```

So that the original verifier could be written into:

```
def verify_multiply(a: int, b: int, c: int, raise_on_error=True):
    if a * b == c:
        return True
    else:
        error_msg = f"{a} * {b} != {c}"
        error_hanlder(error_msg, raise_on_error)
```

But on second thought, when `raise_on_error` is `False`, `error_handler` will `return False` to `verify_multiply`, not from `verify_multiply` to its caller (which is my intent), right?

Is there any way to wrap the error handling code into a separate function to be re-used, and let `False` be returned to `verify_multiply`'s caller when `raise_on_error` is not `True`?

I am asking this question because the error handling snippet was needed by a handful verifiers,
and it feels awkward to repeat the same code over and over. But the return point is my concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you return the result of the `error_handler` invocation?

```py
def verify_multiply(a: int, b: int, c: int, raise_on_error=True):
    if a * b == c:
        return True
    else:
        error_msg = f"{a} * {b} != {c}"
        return error_handler(error_msg, raise_on_error)
```

The `error_handler` function only returns when `raise_on_error == False`, in the other case, an error is raised, which would get raised from `verify_multiply` even with the added `return`.

Or here's another way to refactor:

```py
def error_handler(error_msg, raise_on_error=True):
    if raise_on_error:
        raise ValueError(error_msg)
    else:
        log.error(error_msg)


def verify_multiply(a: int, b: int, c: int, raise_on_error=True):
    if a * b == c:
        return True
    else:
        error_msg = f"{a} * {b} != {c}"
        error_handler(error_msg, raise_on_error)
        return False
```

I think this is a bit more consistent and easy to read since you can see the return value of `verify_multiply` at a glance and `raise_on_error` isn't expected to both return something and raise.